# What does probability density mean and how can it be greater than 1?

Tags: probability

I have been reading several other questions, but I have not managed to understand the concept.

I have been taught that,

The pdf allows determining the probability that a random variable 
$X$, take infinite real values between a range $a, b$. Therefore is defined as: $P(a\le X\le b)=\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. And the area under the curve between the same interval, represents the probability.

I thought I had understood the concept, however I have read in other answers to similar questions, that:

$1)$ PDF is not a probability

$2)$ Then, according to the $1)$, it is unbounded.

Then it comes to my head to ask,

What is the probability density function really?

And I thought the answer is in the name itself, specifically in *density*.

I read that the pdf, gives me information about the probability of the continuous random variable, but NOT the probability. But, **what is this information?** I have a slight idea of what this information can be, it would be how acumulated are the values in a certain range $a, b$ and hence the name density, but I do not even know if this is correct.

So, **what does the probability density function really represent?** Without calculus concepts, if not that, I want to understand the concept.

And if the concept of probability density function is **not** a probability, **Why is it associated with the area under the curve? If it is assumed that the area under the curve is the probability?**

Comment: The equation you write as definition should rather read $P(a\le X\le b)=\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$. - But as you rightfully say, the pdf itself or its values are not probabilities, but the area under the curve between two bounds is a probability

Comment: Thanks Hagen, edited

Comment: Hagen, So, what are the values of the pdf? Or is it useless, and the only thing that matters to us is the area under its curve? The shape of the curve should also give us some information, right?

Comment: If the PDF is not a probability by itself. So it would be correct to say that it is a function that, through its area, allows us to calculate probability?

Comment: You have the explicit definition...what's more to be said?  For instance, to get the uniform probability on, say, the interval $[a,b]$ we use the constant function $\frac 1{b-a}$.  If $b-a$ is small, say, $=.01$, then this is the constant function $100$. Certainly greater than $1$, hence that constant is not itself a probability.

Comment: @EduardoS. That's the gist of it, yeah. Not that it has to be a function (if any single value has a positive probability of occurring, the density "function" would be infinite there).

Comment: Yes that sounds correct. Defining it in this way implies that such a function must be strictly non-negative and have total area $1$ beneath it but no other restrictions apply.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF is a *density*. As such it is related to a primal measure defined on the range of the random variable $X$. If $X$ is real-valued and takes values in some predefined interval $(a,b)\>\subset{\mathbb R}$ then the primal measure available in this range is the *euclidean measure*, generated by the idea $\mu\bigl([u,v]\bigr)=v-u$ when $u\leq v$.

If $X$ is a nice continuous random variable then the probability that $X=c$ is zero for all $c\in(a,b)$. But for any short interval $[u,v]$ of positive length we may expect that the probability $P\bigl(X\in [u,v]\bigr)$ has an interesting positive value. This value depends (i)  on the place of $[u,v]$ within the range $(a,b)$ of $X$ and (ii) on the length $v-u$ of this interval. It is the essence of a density that this dependence can be covered in a formula of the form
$$P\bigl(X\in[u,v]\bigr)\approx f(u)\mu\bigl([u,v]\bigr)=f(u)\>(v-u)\qquad(0<v-u\ll1)\ .$$
If we have such a formula for a given random variable $X$ then the function $f$ is called the *probability density* of $X$. For a given $u\in(a,b)$ the value $f(u)$  does the following: If $J$ is a very short interval containing the point $u$ then $$P(X\in J)\approx f(u)\>\mu(J)\ ,$$
where $\mu$ denotes the euclidean measure on ${\mathbb R}$.